# WSO2: Unable to connect to websocket API using wscat

Tags: websocket, wso2

I have a problem connecting to my created API using wscat.
I did create API using tutorial on https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/4.0.0/tutorials/streaming-api/create-and-publish-websocket-api/
But in last step I cannot connect to API using wscat.
I am getting 404 response or Invalid URL response.
Do you know where can be problem?

Edit:
I have found similar problem here, but I don't know how to fix it.
https://github.com/wso2/api-manager/issues/93

Comment: Do you see any error logs in the server?

Comment: currently I can see only response from wscat:
      throw new SyntaxError(`Invalid URL: ${address}`);
      ^

SyntaxError: Invalid URL: 'ws://localhost:9099/chats/1.0.0/notifications'
    at initAsClient (C:\Users\bouska42\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\wscat\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:673:13)
    at new WebSocket (C:\Users\bouska42\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\wscat\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:85:7)
    at cont (C:\Users\bouska42\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\wscat\bin\wscat:273:16)
    at Object.<anonymous>

Comment: So you can't access the backend service via wscat?

Comment: No currently I can't. I have followed tutorial which I sent link. I am using wscat command which I have found on Try Out tab for given websocket API. I just generate curl and copy it

Comment: @Pubci do you know where can be problem?

Comment: I guess the issue is with wscat and how it can be used in a windows machine

Comment: @Pubci I think it was because of '' on start and end of URL. Now I get "error: Unexpected server response: 404" from wscat and in API Manager console I get:
ERROR - InboundWebSocketProcessor No matching API found to dispatch the request
ERROR - InboundWebsocketSourceHandler Endpoint not found for port : 9099 tenant domain : null

Comment: Did you follow 2.c in step 2 - https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/design/create-api/create-streaming-api/create-a-websocket-streaming-api/#step-2-configure-the-topics

Comment: @Pubci yes I did set up topics as shown in this tutorial, but still cannot get to this API

Comment: @Pubci I have found out that URL for my websocket API is wss://localhost:8099/chats/1.0.0 but in Try Out section of devportal I see ws://localhost:9099/chats/1.0.0/rooms/{roomID} which is on different port. When I use 8099 port I get Error: socket hang up. But when I use 9099 I get error: Unexpected server response: 404.

Comment: You should use the port 9099. It doesn't matter the backend port used here. The API Gateway proxies the request.

Comment: @Pubci so when I use 9099 I get error: Unexpected server response: 404